# object movement in simulator-gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from gazebo tutorial link
i learn to spawn object in gazebo but
can anyone tell me how to move these objects in gazebo
For example if i want to move object under force of 1 N/m in some x direction
how will i do it
also please give me link of tutorial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49916/object-movement-in-simulator-gazebo/) by [iit.saurav](https://answers.ros.org/users/3743/iit.saurav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/CreatingASpinningTopInGazebo) here you can find out how you can a apply a downwards force

```
rosservice call gazebo/apply_body_wrench '{body_name: "top::my_top" , wrench: { force: { x: 0.0, y: 0, z: -0.1 } , torque: { x: 0.0, y: 0 , z: 0.0 } }, start_time: 10000000000, duration: -1000000000 }'
```

Just apply a force in x-direction.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1